# Using variables in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am trying to pull data out of a database by passing an array with the fields in it.

```
browse_fields = array ('id', 'name', 'weight');
```

Here is the funcation:

```
function browse($id, $fields) {
    $data = array();
    $fields2 = $fields;
    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $fields) . '`';
    $query = mysql_query("...");
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            foreach($fields2 as $key) {
                $data[] = array("$key" => $row["$key"]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

I need my an array in an array for the output.  But I am getting an array in an array in an array.  I suspect my problem is here: `$data[] = array("$key" => $row["$key"]);` but I am apparently to dense to make it work properly.

Comment: just set $data[$key]=$row[$key];

Comment: the db querry returns the feild name, which is the $key so that loop is redundnet

Comment: also you don't need your if(mysql_num_rows... the while will skip if it doesnt have results

Comment: Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code should look like is:

```
function browse($id, $fields) {
    $data = array();
    $fields2 = $fields;
    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $fields) . '`';
    $query = mysql_query("...");
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        $rec = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            foreach($fields2 as $key) {
                $rec[$key] = $row["$key"];
            }
            $data[] = $rec;
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

This will give you the desired result. You need to create a keyed array for each record as opposed to each field.

Comment: you basically took my comment and put it as an answer

Comment: @SethMcClaine comment wasn't there when I started the answer ... this solution is wrong anyway I'm in the process of revising...

Comment: @SethMcClaine The problem with both of our original solutions is it would have kept overwriting the same elements in the $data array for each record so the op would have ended up with a 1 dimensional array that contains only the fields of the last record in the set

Comment: I just had to move the $data[] = $rec; up above the previous '}' and it worked fine.

Comment: @user2499455 That was the intent ... updated the answer to reflect the working code.

Answer (score 0):

Cant help it without seeing actual output . But I think replacing your foreach with

```
foreach($fields2 as $key) {
            $data[$key] = $row["$key"];
        }
```

can help you.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is your problem, but you should try

```
$newitem = array("$key" => $row["$key"]);
array_push($data, $newitem);
```

within that inner foreach.